# React Hooks, object state is not updating onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am using React Hooks and am created a form to submit blog posts. I am having trouble writing the submitPost logic. I have a post, and setPost variable. setPost doesn't seem to be updating post with the new post in the submitPost function, so my api call function createPost isn't receiving the new req.body. But when I created a second function changePost(), post is updated.
This is my code.

```
export default function NewPost({ props }) {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({
    title: "",
    img: "",
    content: "",
    user_id: 0,
  });
  const [img, setImg] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUser = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await verifyUser();
        console.log(response);
        setUserId(response.user.id);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    handleUser();
  });

  const changePost = () => {
    const newPost = {
      title: title,
      img: img,
      content: content,
      user_id: userId,
    };

    setPost(newPost);
    console.log(post);
  };
  const submitPost = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(userId);
    try {
      console.log(title);
      changePost();
      console.log("submitPost", post);
      await createPost(post);
      props.history.push("/posts");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  console.log(post);
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav />
      <div class="ui main text container segment mt-100">
        <div class="ui huge header salmon">New Blog </div>
        <form class="ui form" onSubmit={submitPost}>
          <div class="field">
            <label> Title </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="title"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <label> Image </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="img"
              value={img}
              onChange={(e) => setImg(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="image"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <label> Body </label>
            <textarea
              name="content"
              value={content}
              onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="blog post goes here"
            >
              {" "}
            </textarea>
          </div>

          <input class="ui teal big basic button" type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining `handleUser` inside the useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. You're trying to create a post where your `post` variable is not yet updated. You don't need to create so many variables, just use the `post` variable.
Try using the below code.

```
export default function NewPost({ props }) {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({
    title: "",
    img: "",
    content: "",
    user_id: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUser = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await verifyUser();
        console.log(response);
        setPost({...post, user_id: response.user.id});
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    handleUser();
  });

  const submitPost = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(userId);
    try {
      console.log(title);
      console.log("submitPost", post);
      await createPost(post);
      props.history.push("/posts");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  console.log(post);
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav />
      <div class="ui main text container segment mt-100">
        <div class="ui huge header salmon">New Blog </div>
        <form class="ui form" onSubmit={submitPost}>
          <div class="field">
            <label> Title </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setPost({...post, title: e.target.value})}
              placeholder="title"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <label> Image </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="img"
              value={img}
              onChange={(e) => setPost({...post, img: e.target.value})}
              placeholder="image"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <label> Body </label>
            <textarea
              name="content"
              value={content}
              onChange={(e) => setPost({...post, content: e.target.value})}
              placeholder="blog post goes here"
            >
              {" "}
            </textarea>
          </div>

          <input class="ui teal big basic button" type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
just do this .

useEffect(()=>{
},[JSON.stringify(post)])..
```

setPost({ title,img,content,user_id});